# Why is Helm push command to Google Cloud Artifact Registry failing from Github Actions?

Tags: github-actions, helm3, google-artifact-registry

I'm using Github Actions and in one of my steps I'm trying to push my Helm chart up to my Google Cloud Artifact repository.

Here is my step:

```
  - name: Package & Upload Helm Chart
    run: |
      ${{ secrets.GH_ACTIONS_SA }} | helm registry login https://${{ env.GKE_ZONE }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ env.GC_PROJECT_ID }}/web-${{ env.RBI_ENV }}-django -u _json_key --password-stdin
      helm version
      helm package main/charts/website
      ls -la
      helm push website-0.1.0.tgz oci://${{ env.GKE_ZONE }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ env.GC_PROJECT_ID }}/web-${{ env.RBI_ENV }}-django/charts
```

The Github action output is:

```
Login Succeeded
version.BuildInfo***Version:"v3.9.0", GitCommit:"7ceeda6c585217a19a1131663d8cd1f7d641b2a7", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.17.5"***
Successfully packaged chart and saved it to: /home/runner/work/***/***/website-0.1.0.tgz
drwxr-xr-x  4 runner docker   4096 Jun 29 16:26 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 runner docker   4096 Jun 29 16:25 ..
-rwx------  1 runner docker  11156 Jun 29 16:26 get_helm.sh
drwxr-xr-x 10 runner docker   4096 Jun 29 16:26 main
-rw-r--r--  1 runner docker 139399 Jun 29 16:26 website-0.1.0.tgz
Error: failed commit on ref "manifest-sha256:dfc14c1945cab5f23a987efc975613f265ab15e20e5cd36f62956f3a607dcfe7": invalid content digest in response: invalid checksum digest format
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I can run these same commands on my local machine (Mac) and it pushes up just fine with:

```
Pushed: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/***/web-staging-django/website:0.1.0
Digest: sha256:dad429ef46206f736dd403e80bea1536a7eb37c7f0d02bb7609f558a0f27b4ec
```

Any ideas why I am getting the error `invalid content digest in response: invalid checksum digest format` with my `helm push` command?

Answer (score 2):

The reason I was getting this error was because my `LOCATION` in the URL was wrong.

I was using `us-central1-a` and instead I should have been using `us-central1`

What helped me identify this was by adding the `--debug` flag on the `helm push` command.